# E0369 when concatenating string references

Tags: operator-overloading, rust, stringstream

The example below shows two functions `foo()` and `bar()` that attempt to concatenate two strings. The code will not compile if the left-hand side `+` argument is a `&String`.

This is exemplified in `foo()` which fails to compile with error message **[E0369]**. The function `bar()` shows that I can bail out of the situation by cloning the LHS argument. My intuition suggests that this cloning should be redundant.

Why do I have to `clone()` the LHS argument? Is this a reflection of the current implementation state of the Rust `+`-operator or is there an intentional deeper thinking behind it?

```
// rustc 1.7.0-nightly (110df043b 2015-12-13)

fn foo(a: &String, i: i32) -> String {
    a + &i.to_string() // .. '+' cannot be applied to type & .. String [E0369]
}

fn bar(a: &String, i: i32) -> String { 
    a.clone() + &i.to_string() // Ok
}

#[test]
fn my_test() {
    assert!(foo(&"s".to_string(), 42) == "s42"); // fn foo(..) failed to compile
    assert!(bar(&"s".to_string(), 42) == "s42"); // Ok
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you check the documentation for the [`Add`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html) trait (or the current [nightly docs for `Add`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ops/trait.Add.html)), you will see:

```rust
impl<'a> Add<&'a str> for String
```

This is the *only* implementation of `Add` for `String`.  This signature means it takes the left-hand side *by value*, not by reference, hence the need to call `clone()`.

To clarify, `Add<&str>` for `String` is just a wrapper around `String::push_str`, which appends to the end of a `String`, re-using the existing allocation.  Doing this through an immutable pointer is *impossible*, and doing it through a mutable pointer would be *really* weird and counter to reasonable expectations.  Thus, it requires the LHS to be passed by value.

Depending on who you ask, the `+` operator being defined for *any* form of `String` is a wart, so whether or not additional forms get defined is... well, an open question as far as I know.

Comment: +1 @DK Thank you for the answer. So that means external cloning of String `a` is both necessary and implies no waste of cycles.

Answer (score 3):

A `&String` is a very strange thing. You almost always should prefer `&str`.

What caught my eye is you saying

> So that means external cloning of String `a` is both necessary and implies no waste of cycles.

Well, you are wasting cycles - `&i.to_string()` allocates and then discards its buffer.

`to_string` is part of the trait [`ToString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/string/trait.ToString.html). It's implemented by default for `Display` types as

```
impl<T: fmt::Display + ?Sized> ToString for T {
    #[inline]
    fn to_string(&self) -> String {
        use core::fmt::Write;
        let mut buf = String::new();
        let _ = buf.write_fmt(format_args!("{}", self));
        buf.shrink_to_fit();
        buf
    }
}
```

Note that this is writing directly into a `String`. You can do the same for `foo` like

```
use std::fmt::Write;

fn foo(a: &str, i: i32) -> String {
    let mut buf: String = a.into();
    write!(&mut buf, "{}", i).unwrap();
    buf
}
```

Even better would be to intelligently preallocate `buf` to a sufficient size. This is a worst `a.len() + 11`, since `i` will contribute at most 11 characters to the string. You might be able to do better if you know `i` is in a more restricted range.

```
use std::fmt::Write;

fn foo(a: &str, i: i32) -> String {
    let mut buf = String::with_capacity(a.len() + 11);
    write!(&mut buf, "{}{}", a, i).unwrap();
    buf
}
```

You might at this point be wondering why am I doing this. That is a reasonable question.

I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Unbeknown to @DK and @Veedrac they collectively actually answered my motivating challenge behind my question.

I wanted a simple way to build Strings for my pet project in the way I am used to with C++ `stringstream`. The answer from @DK implies that I need to use an reference vector to forward a mutable reference of my string. The answer from @Veedrac shows ways to generically append to the String.

For anyone interested in a toy example of how C++ stringstream can be emulated, I copy the code here.

```
use std::ops::Shl;
use std::fmt::Write;
use std::fmt::Display;

// Mutable reference vector
struct Mr<'a, T: 'a> {
    mr: &'a mut T
}

// Implements Shl trait for String reference vector Mr<String>
impl<'a, U: Display> Shl<U> for Mr<'a, String> {
    type Output = Self;
    fn shl(self, other: U) -> Self {
        write!(self.mr, "{}", other);
        self
    }
 }

 #[test]
 fn test_shl() {
     let mut s = String::new();

     // Emulates C++ stringstream
     Mr{mr: &mut s} << "The " << "answer " << "is "<< 40 + 2;

     assert!(s == "The answer is 42");
 }
```